# Imagemapster not working fully when implemented in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, imagemapster

I have been using Imagemapster on a website built in CakePHP. I have successfully implemented the code 
[outside of the CakePHP environment](http://hairylegs.com/lesliegarfield/mapsearch/map.html)

However, when I use this same code, [slightly altered for CakePHP](http://lg.graves.com/Properties/search_sale/sale), I am having issues with the image switch upon rollover and the rendering of the checkbox list (which is auto-generated via Imagemapster). You can see upon rollover that the imagemap is being detected and that there are multiple rollover areas on the main image but that is the limit of the functionality that carried over to CakePHP. (I have checked the image paths to the alternate images in my code and they are all correct.)

I have checked the Imagemapster FAQ and many other sources for troubleshooting this but am coming up blank. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

check the error log (this one is from chrome dev tools):

```
sale:446  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
site.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
2sale:720 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
bootstrap.css.map:1 GET http://lg.graves.com/css/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)
```